# How does the shape_extraction command (from package dtwclust) work?

Tags: r

I intend to extract a time-series shape using the shape_extraction command. However, I do not understand how it has been implemented (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dtwclust/versions/1.3.0/topics/shape_extraction).

Here is some sample code

```
# Sample data
data(uciCT)

# Subset of interest, normalized
X <- t(sapply(CharTraj[1:5], zscore))

# Obtain centroid series
C <- shape_extraction(X, znorm = FALSE)

# Result
matplot(t(X), type = "l", col = 1:5)
points(C)
```

Comment: More specifically, why do I get an error when I modify X to X <- t(sapply(CharTraj[1:20], zscore))

Comment: That website has a very old version of the documentation, [here's](https://rdrr.io/cran/dtwclust/man/shape_extraction.html) a newer one. In any case, what error are you getting specifically?